# SSJS Post request error

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs

I'm trying to delete contacts based on DE. So far I'm testing the code on cloud page but eventually, it will be used as part of automation.  I'm successfully retrieving a token but struggle to execute the call to delete contacts and receive an error: *Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.*

The similar call seems to work fine when tested in Postman.

```
 <script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core", "1");

// Authorization 

var url = '<auth endpoint>; 
var contentType = 'application/json'; 
var payload = '{"client_id": "<clientid>","client_secret": "<clientsecret>", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'; // Specifying the access credentials

var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload); 
var accessToken = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]).access_token;

  if (accessToken !='') {
  Platform.Response.Write(accessToken);
  }
  else
  {
  Platform.Response.Write('Auth failed');
  }


  var payLoadDeletion = {
 "deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes",
 "targetList": {
   "listType": {
     "listTypeID": 3
   },
   "listKey": "2A052B10-24B7-42A4-81A2-B91E0E1E48B4"
 },
 "deleteListWhenCompleted": false,
 "deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": false
}


  try {

 var urlDelete = '<API endpoint>/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference';
 var contentTypeDelete = 'application/json';
  var headerNames = ["Authorization"]; 
  var s1="Bearer ";
  var headerValues = s1.concat(accessToken); 
   var reply;
   var result = HTTP.Post(urlDelete, contentTypeDelete, payLoadDeletion, headerNames, headerValues); 

     } catch (err) {
         Platform.Response.Write("<br><br>Error: " + err);
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two adaptions you need to make to get your example to work:

- Supply the payload as string using `Stringify(payLoadDeletion)`
- Supply the headerValues as Array: `var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];`

Comment: Thank you so much, Markus! It solved my problem!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help!